# SQL delete query optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sqlplus, sql-delete

```
DELETE edms_personalisation 
WHERE  mail_id NOT IN (SELECT mail_id 
                       FROM   edms_mail) 
       AND rownum <= 25000;
```

Hello, can the SQL (run from a SQLPLUS interface) above be written in a more efficient way?

I was recently alerted to the fact that the edms_personalisation table has approx 80 Million rows and the edms_mail table has approx 120,000 rows.

I want to create a clear down script that only affect a limited number of rows per run so I can stick it on a Cron Job and get it to run every 5 minutes or so.

Any ideas welcome.

(Note: Appropriate indexes do EXIST on the DB tables)

Comment: Try running an `EXPLAIN` on the query to see what it exactly does.

Comment: Why don't you copy the rows that DO match something in `edms_mail` into another table, then delete the original and rename the new one?  Make sure you deal appropriately with any indexes, views, stored procedures and so on.

Comment: I suppose, deletion by using join will be more efficient, since IN search is not sargable.  `Delete edms_personalisation from edms_personalisation ep left join edms_mail em on ep.mail_id=em.mail_id where ep.mail_id is null and ROWNUM<25000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE edms_personalisation p 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' 
                   FROM   edms_mail m 
                   WHERE  m.mail_id = p.mail_id) 
       AND rownum <= 25000;
```

or

```
DELETE edms_personalisation 
WHERE  mail_id IN (SELECT mail_id FROM edms_personalisation 
                   MINUS 
                   SELECT mail_id FROM edms_mail) 
       AND rownum <= 25000;
```

If Oracle I would have written a `PL/SQL` to bulk collect all the qualifying mail ids to be deleted.And make a FORALL DELETE querying the index directly(Bulk Binding). You can do it in batch too.

Otherwise since the 'to be deleted' table is too big, wiser to copy the good data into temp table, truncate the table, and reload it from temp. When it has to be done in a frequent cycle, the above methods have to be used!

Try this! Good Luck!

Comment: Will this second idea run quicker?  And should this second one have the ROWNUM limiter on?  I am guessing that it doesn't need the 'p' short name for the edms_personalisation table either.

Comment: 'p' is my typo, and it wont harm anyways. The second i chose, becuase being mail_id having the index, the  i expect the subquery to run faster. And later deleting it directly querying index like hash key. The ROWNUM , sorry I missed it, you can always add it.

Comment: To confirm this first alternative you suggested definitely runs a lot faster.  Haven't tried the second one yet.  Thanks Maheswaran

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the delete statement in the question will work just fine.
   The question is how much amount of redo log will the delete
   statement generate.
2. General rule of thumb would be to delete rows batch wise with a
   commit in it although batch size shold not burst out the online redo
   log files. [i suppose the question is related to ORACLE]
3. If the delete is once in a time activity but you are doing it every
   5 minutes with a batch of 25000 to cope up with the amount of rows
   to be deleted then copy out the required rows on to a new table,
   truncate the actual table and transfer data from new table to actual
   table. Of course doing it every five minutes would not make sense
   according to me.
4. If the data to be deleted will be huge for the first run but not for the subsequent 
   runs then i would suggest to follow the method mentioned in 2nd point for the first run
   and the method mentioned in 1st point for the subsequent runs.

***DISCLAIMER: I think others would have faced the same problem and would have solved it with a better solution then mentioned above.***

Answer (score 0):

You can `SET ROWCONT N` to limit the rows affected by next batch to `N`. Eg.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10
GO

DELETE edms_personalisation
WHERE mail_id NOT IN (SELECT mail_id FROM edms_mail)
AND ROWNUM <= 25000;
GO
```

Will delete not more than 10 rows.

Otherwise, I would think about using bulk copy (or [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms162802.aspx)) to copy the data to a new table, skipping the rows you planned to delete. FYI:

- This will work if the table doesn't change often, or you pre-create
  INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers to replay all changes made to the
  source table during the copying process.
- If you use bcp, than the `out/queryout` will not block the source
  table, but `in` will block the destination table.
- You should pre-create all indexes on the destination table with
  proper [fill factor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), or otherwise you will have to create them
  on a table with a lot of data after you are done copying, and this
  will take much time.